# R gghighlight sizing

Tags: r, ggplot2

Could you please help me with issue below:

My goal is to highlight some data points in a geom_col() ggplot with the gghighlight() function.

If I want to highlight more than 5 data points, everything works fine, but if want to do the same with less data points, the sizing of the highlighted points get to big.

Here is a simple example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gghighlight)

df <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("1990-01-01"),as.Date("2019-12-01"),by="months"),
                 Value = runif(360,min=-4,max=4))

Dates <- as.Date(c("2000-01-01","2001-05-01","2002-08-01","2003-07-01",
"2004-06-01","2008-05-01","2010-02-01","2012-09-01","2012-10-01","2017-01-01","2019-04-01"))

head(df)
        Date      Value
1 1990-01-01 -0.6268077
2 1990-02-01 -0.4959038
3 1990-03-01 -0.3501759
4 1990-04-01  1.5419100
5 1990-05-01  2.2753423
6 1990-06-01  1.5790881
```

ggplot with highlighting more than 5 data points:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Date, y=Value)) +
  geom_col() + 
  gghighlight(Date %in% Dates)
```

Output :
[good example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibkoz.png)

ggplot with highlighting less than 5 data points:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Date, y=Value)) +
  geom_col() + 
  gghighlight(Date %in% Dates[1:3])
```

Output:
[bad example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjJzF.png)

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] gghighlight_0.2.0 ggplot2_3.2.1     dplyr_0.8.3      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.3       rstudioapi_0.10  magrittr_1.5     tidyselect_0.2.5 munsell_0.5.0    colorspace_1.4-1
 [7] R6_2.4.1         rlang_0.4.2      tools_3.6.0      grid_3.6.0       gtable_0.3.0     withr_2.1.2     
[13] yaml_2.2.0       lazyeval_0.2.2   assertthat_0.2.1 tibble_2.1.3     lifecycle_0.1.0  crayon_1.3.4    
[19] purrr_0.3.3      farver_2.0.3     glue_1.3.1       labeling_0.3     compiler_3.6.0   pillar_1.4.3    
[25] scales_1.1.0     pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

Comment: Not sure why that happens with `gghighlight`, but you do not necessarily need an extra package to get this type of output; `ggplot(df, aes(x=Date, y=Value)) + geom_col(colour=ifelse(df$Date %in% Dates[1:3], "black", "grey"))` works fine.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will take than your solution.